# Palette (Android Support v22) doesn't generate Swatches

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, palette

First of all, I never used Palette, when i wanted to start with it, I see that all tutorials and blogs talk about v21 and not v22.

My problem is that I have a Swatch (In position 0 of swatch's array [palette.getSwatches().get(0)]) that returns always black (title and body), here is an example as I'm using this, maybe it's wrong but I'm copying this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

```
        Palette.from(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prueba2)).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            text.setTextColor(palette.getVibrantSwatch().getBodyTextColor());
            text.setBackgroundColor(palette.getVibrantSwatch().getTitleTextColor());
        }
    });
```

When I start this App (I have an activity with a textView and an ImageView) it closes saying this

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v7.graphics.Palette$Swatch.getBodyTextColor()' on a null object reference
        at com.alfondo.projectpalette.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)"
```

EDIT: This is my drawable. (I cant't post imgs) https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeulu.jpg

Comment: Checkout this example http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-v7-palette-demo.html

Answer (score 1):

first create bitmap of image then using picasso palette get color of image and set that color to collapsible toolbar

```
  // get bitmap of image and generate toolbar color by passing bitmap to palette


     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nature);
                Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        // get muted color from bitmap using palette and set this to collapsible toolbar

        @Override
                    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
                            collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just check whether pallete is null or not

```
 public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        if(palette!=null){
            text.setTextColor(palette.getVibrantSwatch().getBodyTextColor());
            text.setBackgroundColor(palette.getVibrantSwatch().getTitleTextColor());
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it doesn't work cause I have a Palette and a Swatch with black body and black text. My problem is that I need to generate the Swatches and I'm thinking about my problem is not the code, just my Image.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the swatch is null not the palette before you allocate the colour to the view

```
Palette.from(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prueba2).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
      public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
           Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
           if(vibrantSwatch != null){
              text.setTextColor(vibrantSwatch.getBodyTextColor());
              text.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getTitleTextColor())
           }
      }
});
```